Source for Shofar customs
What are the different practices and sources for different practices of the quality of the shofar sounds (not Rashi vs Tosfos (ie: 3 vs 9 truah)); ie: where the note goes up and down (rootoos, terootoos), peshutos etc...

See here for a good summary https://www.eichlers.com/teka-beshofar-expanded-edition-paperback.html?srsltid=AfmBOoqQwYyFG4qMJuIQ9vjz0G07VzIC4VLH1GC21jkk1K8fhojzqh29IEg

@N.T. Out of curiosity does it address the specific question? The sources for the different customs?
